# Looking for a fast way to get the texel density of my object in Maya

Tags: maya

In Maya the code below works really well however with dense meshes around 50K tris it takes a while to compute.
When I use the mel version in python `mel.eval("uvTkDoGetTexelDensity;")` it works really fast however I can't print out that mel.eval to give me the texel density.
Is there a faster way to get texel density?

```
texture_size = 2048
desired_Tex_density = 10.24
def get_texel_density(faces, size= texture_size):
    ws_area = 0.0
    uv_area = 0.0
    for face in faces:
        ws_area += face.getArea(space='world')
        #ws_area = ws_area + face.getArea(space = "world")
    
        uv_area += face.getUVArea() # By default I hope it picks the current uv set

    # Get the square root of the area
    ws_area = math.sqrt(ws_area)
    uv_area = math.sqrt(uv_area)

    px_area = uv_area * size
    texel_density = (px_area / ws_area)
    return texel_density
```

Answer (score 1):

Used the polyEvaluate command to calculate the uv area and woldspace area on the selected object instead of iterating on each face.
Gave the same result and works super fast for dense geo.
Perfect for what I needed!